# Assigning a Readonly Field via Virtual Member in Abstract Class's Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I know there are similar questions already asked here on SO, but specifically my question deals with scenarios involving setting a `readonly` field by calling a virtual member in an abstract class's constructor.

Consider the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string,object> _readonlyCache;

    protected abstract IDictionary<string,object> SetCache();

    protected FooBase()
    {
        _readonlyCache = SetCache();
    }
}
```

Questions:

1) Is this just flat-out bad design?

2) Is there a better design?

I'm aware that you could declare implementers of `FooBase` as `sealed` and that will insure that only the correct implementation of `SetCache()` is called. What I don't like about that is there is no way to **enforce** that implementers must be marked as `sealed`. Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely something to be avoided if possible - calling virtual methods within a constructor is always a bit smelly, as you'll be executing code before the subclass gets to perform initialization - its constructor body won't have executed. This is true regardless of whether the subclass is sealed or not; you're in a fundamentally nasty situation.

You might want to consider making the subclass constructor pass the cache up to the constructor:

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string,object> _readonlyCache;

    protected FooBase(IDictionary<string,object> cache)
    {
        _readonlyCache = cache;
    }
}
```

That way the *direct* subclass gets to decide what to do - it might be abstract and take a cache from a further-derived class, for example, or it might construct its own.

Comment: It looks like going this route would force a subclass to create a static method that would create the cache. Is that a good way to go about it?

Comment: @Didaxis: It wouldn't necessarily have to create a static method. It could just use a collection initializer, for example - or even pass a null reference, or use the same cache for all instances. It's up to the subclass to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, it's bad design, *because* you can't force an implementer to be sealed.  (I don't see how you could ever reasonably force that kind of design decision on someone else's code; it's not up to you to control someone else's level of abstraction.)

2) Yes: for example, make `ReadOnlyCache` a property that is either abstract, or is non-abstract and calls the abstract method on first use to get it's value:

```
private readonly IDictionary<string,object> _readonlyCache;

private IDictionary<string,object> ReadOnlyCache
{
    get
    {
        return _readonlyCache ?? _readonlyCache = GetEmptyCache();
    }
}

protected abstract IDictionary<string,object> GetEmptyCache();
```